# Apache Tomcat and HTTPS on deployed application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, https

I use Apache Tomcat and I configure it for HTTPS connection (at the moment using a self signed certificate).
I wondering if I should set other in my java code (I use Spring) or Tomcat provides connection encrypted for all the data. For example if I use FTP, download end send file etc...
Maybe is a stupid question but it is important use https for my connection.
Thanks, best regards

Comment: FTP is a different protocol than HTTP and they use completely different port, so if you secure your HTTP connection, FTP is not secured; you will need to secure FTP (sFTP generally on top of SSH and port 22)

Comment: so my Rest web service are encrypted because they use standard HTTPS port, but if I use FTP in my java code I have to implement sFTP? I ask because I'm trying to make file exchange through web service but I have several problem so I thought to use sFTP

Comment: how do you use FTP now? Apache Tomcat is Http server, not FTP

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to use Rest web service to exchange file, but whereas I have several problem I thought to use sFTP in java, but I have never used it before now

Comment: @luca you'd better fix your web service than deploy a ftp server for these goals

Comment: ok, in my java code I don't have to do nothing, when I call the web services from other java code I have only to use https and all is encrypted, right?

Comment: yes, encryption is transparent and app should not know is it encrypted or not. web server does all the job.